# There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404) No static resource userList

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, liquibase

I'm using Docker with db and liqibase on spring boot app. I'm sorry if its too easy for you)

db.local.yml

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    container_name: CarService_DB
    hostname: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
    drop-first: true
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"`
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.ithub</groupId>
    <artifactId>carservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>carservice</name>
    <description>carservice</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>ru/sleed/mvc/**/model/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>ru/sleed/mvc/**/entity/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>book</doctype>
                            <attributes>
                                <snippets>${project.build.directory}/generated-snippets</snippets>
                            </attributes>
                            <sourceDirectory>src/docs/asciidocs</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-docs</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/userList")
public class Controller {
    private final List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    @GetMapping
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> toSee = users;
        return toSee;
    }
}
```

Everything with liquibase changelog is ok

How can I fix 404? Docker is running

Comment: Could you write your package name for controller and your curl request that hits this endpoint? It seems to me spring can’t see your controller class. That’s why you get 404 for this endpoint.

Comment: /src/main/java/ru/sleed/controller/SpController.java

Comment: org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource userList.